# JSON type mismatch or org.json.jsonecxeption

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

The link is 
http://iipacademy.in/askpoll/ten_feed.php

exception is in onPostExecute() method  (4th line) :

```
Log.i("result", result);
try {
    if (result != null) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result); // erreor
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            TopTenGetterSetter obj = new TopTenGetterSetter();  


            obj.setQ(objJson.getString("question"));
            obj.setA(objJson.getString("option1"));
            obj.setB(objJson.getString("option2"));
            obj.setC(objJson.getString("option3"));
            obj.setD(objJson.getString("option4"));

            polls.add(obj);
                        }

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790): org.json.JSONException: Value response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at com.example.askpollie.LatestPollParticipated$FetchingEventsDetails.onPostExecute(LatestPollParticipated.java:188)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at com.example.askpollie.LatestPollParticipated$FetchingEventsDetails.onPostExecute(LatestPollParticipated.java:1)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 03:20:45.447: W/System.err(2790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 03:20:45.447: D/dalvikvm(2790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5131K, 55% free 4437K/9672K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
```

Message is an array so what should be its code or how to can it be solved ?

Thanks
in
advance . . .

Comment: given webservice returning `JSONObject` as root element instead of `JSONArray`

Comment: you could use something like `new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser().parse("jsonString");` to get JsonArray.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
org.json.JSONException: Value response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Looks like response is a string not a json array

```
{  // json object node 
    "response": { // json object response
        "result": 1,
        "Message": [ // json array Message
            {        // json object node 
                "pollid": "98",
                 "category": "Entertainment",
                 "question": "what",  //  string
                 "option1": "981.mov",
```

The result is a json object not json array

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Should be

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject response = jObj.getJSONObject("response");
//JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jr = response.getJSONArray("Message");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(i);
String question = jb1.getString("question");
Log.i(".......",question);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Result is not an array, Message is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Log.i("result", result);
try {
    if (result != null) {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("Message");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            TopTenGetterSetter obj = new TopTenGetterSetter();  
            /*
             * [{"job_id":"1","job_staff_id":"","job_name":"Account",
             * "job_detail":"test\r\ntesds","job_start_date":
             * "2013-11-08"
             * ,"job_end_date":"2013-11-10","job_amount":"500"
             * ,"job_progress":"","job_complete_status":"0"}]
             */

            obj.setQ(objJson.getString("question"));
            obj.setA(objJson.getString("option1"));
            obj.setB(objJson.getString("option2"));
            obj.setC(objJson.getString("option3"));
            obj.setD(objJson.getString("option4"));

            polls.add(obj);
            // am = Customer.info.get(pos).getJamount();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), am + result,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

As mario and nfear said, you are trying to cast a JSONObject into a JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

String content JSONObject as root element instead of JSONArray.to get `Message` JSONArray from String you should first get `response` JSONObject then get `Message` JSONArray as:

```
 JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result);
 // get response JSONObject

 JSONObject jsonobj_response = jsonobj.getJSONObject("response");

// get Message JSONArray from jsonobj_response

 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonobj_response.getJSONArray("Message");
  // your code here.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
try {
    if (result != null) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("Message");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            TopTenGetterSetter obj = new TopTenGetterSetter();  
            /*
             * [{"job_id":"1","job_staff_id":"","job_name":"Account",
             * "job_detail":"test\r\ntesds","job_start_date":
             * "2013-11-08"
             * ,"job_end_date":"2013-11-10","job_amount":"500"
             * ,"job_progress":"","job_complete_status":"0"}]
             */

            obj.setQ(objJson.getString("question"));
            obj.setA(objJson.getString("option1"));
            obj.setB(objJson.getString("option2"));
            obj.setC(objJson.getString("option3"));
            obj.setD(objJson.getString("option4"));

            polls.add(obj);
            // am = Customer.info.get(pos).getJamount();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), am + result,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you have posted is having

```
// Key "response" , Value type JsonObject

 JSONObject jsonObject=jsonObjectOfRsponse.getJsonObject(key);

//Key "Message" , Value type Json Array

 JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJsonArray(key);
```

After getting the jsonArray, use this in a loop to parse the Json according to the type of value inside it.

So check if you are parsing the json according to the type of value it is holding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Value response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

You are trying to convert a single object into an array.

Answer (score 0):

better to use GSON library instead of parsing it manually. GSON you can find it on goggling. and sample examples are given with that.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have a json code which is like this below you need to understand that a JSONArray string is enclosed in **[]**, while a JSONObject string is enclosed in **{}**

```
[
{
userId: 1,
id: 1,
title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
body: "quia et suscipit
suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum
reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam
nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
]
```

in this case you need to call the **JSONArray** class and leter get the **JSONObject**

```
// Json Array []
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonData);



// JSON Object {}`
  for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
       JSONObject object =  data.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```