# JSON Parsing fail android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-studio

When i run my app, i got this exception. My code run normally when i use it in my first json parsing app. But when i implement my code in my new app, i got this exception. But the other code is work normally.

```
07-29 11:48:38.269    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-29 11:48:38.269    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
07-29 11:48:38.269    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
07-29 11:48:38.269    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at com.fingerspot.mencobaagain.Product$LoadUsers.doInBackground(Product.java:89)
07-29 11:48:38.279    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at com.fingerspot.mencobaagain.Product$LoadUsers.doInBackground(Product.java:59)
07-29 11:48:38.289    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-29 11:48:38.289    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
07-29 11:48:38.289    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-29 11:48:38.289    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 15
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 16
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 17
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 18
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 19
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-29 11:48:38.299    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-29 11:48:38.309    4670-4679/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 20
07-29 11:48:38.309    4670-4767/com.fingerspot.mencobaagain W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

here's the code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {
            users = new JSONArray(json);

            if (users != null) {
                // looping through All albums

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"errrrrrorrrrr",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String user_id = c.getString("user_id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String display_name = c.getString("display_name");
                    String phone = c.getString("phone");
                    String ym = c.getString("ym");
                    String created_at = c.getString("created_at");
                    String last_login = c.getString("last_login");
                    String updated_at = c.getString("updated_at");
                    // creating new HashMap
                    //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    items.add(new ProductClass(Integer.parseInt(user_id), name, email, display_name,phone, ym, created_at, last_login, updated_at));
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Users: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I expected that there are something wrong with my code to getting json object.

NOTE : The json I used on my old app and my new app is same.

my json object

```
{"DataUser":[{"user_id":1,"name":"Admin HO","email":"admin@kitasatu.net","display_name":null,"phone":null,"ym":null,"status":0,"location_id":0,"last_login":"2015-07-07 07:51:12","active":1,"created_at":"2015-05-02 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-07-07 07:51:12"}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653106/json-type-mismatch-or-org-json-jsonecxeption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse json string to JSON Object first.

```
    {
    "DataUser":[
        {
        "user_id":1,
        "name":"Admin HO",
        "email":"admin@kitasatu.net",
        "display_name":null,
        "phone":null,
        "ym":null,
        "status":0,
        "location_id":0,
        "last_login":"2015-07-07 07:51:12",
        "active":1,
        "created_at":"2015-05-02 00:00:00",
        "updated_at":"2015-07-07 07:51:12"
        }
    ]
   }
```

After that, you should get json array from previous parsed JSON Object. "DataUser"

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        try {
            users = jsonObj.getJSONArray("DataUser");

            if (users != null) {
                // looping through All albums

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"errrrrrorrrrr",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String user_id = c.getString("user_id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String display_name = c.getString("display_name");
                    String phone = c.getString("phone");
                    String ym = c.getString("ym");
                    String created_at = c.getString("created_at");
                    String last_login = c.getString("last_login");
                    String updated_at = c.getString("updated_at");
                    // creating new HashMap
                    //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    items.add(new ProductClass(Integer.parseInt(user_id), name, email, display_name,phone, ym, created_at, last_login, updated_at));
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Users: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: oh thanks for answer. actually i was solved my problem a moment ago by myself :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this not a solution for your problem but you should GSON for parsing your json response.As many open source projects are using gson.As GSON increase code readability and minimize the parsing time by 30% from the traditional ones. Following tutorials will help you to understand it.http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Download Gson.jar from [GSon.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

If you will face problem in creating gson models then you can create them online from [Gson models online](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)